# Calling class method inside lambda function inside class method

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

My class method is declared as follows:

```
void sendCommandToBluetoothModule(String command, SendCommandToBluetoothModuleCallback callback);
```

Where `SendCommandToBluetoothModuleCallback` is:

```
typedef void (*SendCommandToBluetoothModuleCallback)(String);
```

So, I'm making this call:

```
sendCommandToBluetoothModule("AT\r\n", [](String response) -> void {
  Serial.println(response);
});
```

And everything works as expected. The thing is: If I try to call another class member function then I should capture `this`. The moment I change the last piece of code to:

```
sendCommandToBluetoothModule("AT\r\n", [this](String response) -> void {
  Serial.println(response);
});
```

I receive the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to
>   'BluePlotterClient::sendCommandToBluetoothModule(const char [5],
>   BluePlotterClient::setupBluetoothModule()::)'

What I need to do in order to be able to make this call (for example):

```
sendCommandToBluetoothModule("AT\r\n", [this](String response) -> void {
  this->classMemberFunction(response);
});
```

Comment: Only lambdas with empty capture list could be converted to funtion pointer. You could use `std::function` instead of function pointer.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot There are many, many embedded platforms (and GUI frameworks for that matter) that have their own string class - not everyone uses std::string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a lambda with capture as function pointer. When you capture, you add an additional state in the lambda that cannot be contained in a simple function pointer.

To solve that, you can just like the stl does and use a template:

```
template<typename F>
void sendCommandToBluetoothModule(String, F callback) {
    // things
}
```

The type of callback, `F`, can be a function pointer or a lambda, or any function-like object.

If you need type erasure, like storing the callback in a vector or assign it to a data member of a fixed type, you can use `std::function`. Note that this solution sacrifice performance, as it is not as optimizable as a template:

```
void sendCommandToBluetoothModule(String, std::function<void(String)> callback) {
    // things
}
```

That class can hold any copiable function-like objects.